# Oracle 8 database instant client

Tags: php, oracle8

We have an oracle 8.0.5 Database with the following details:

```
- Oracle8 Enterprise Edition Release 8.0.5.0.0 - Production
- PL/SQL Release 8.0.5.0.0 - Production
- CORE Version 4.0.5.0.0 - Production
- TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 8.0.5.0.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 3.3.2.0.0 - Production
```

I am trying to connect to the database from PHP code with no luck.
My Environment:

```
- Windows 7 64 bit
- PHP 5.6
```

Any help please?

Comment: What ways of connecting have you tried so far? (Censor the usernames/passwords/hosts)

Comment: You may need to recompile your PHP. See http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm and http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php